# Concatenating two doc2vec models: Vector dimensions doubled

Tags: machine-learning, concatenation, word2vec, gensim, doc2vec

I have a question regarding concatenating two doc2vec models. I followed the [official gensim IMDB example](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/develop/docs/notebooks/doc2vec-IMDB.ipynb) on `doc2vec` and implemented example data.

When concatenating two models (PV-DM + PV-DBOW), as outlined in the original paper, I wondered that the concatenated model appears not to have 200-dim, like the two input models, but 400-dim:

```
Shape Train(11948, **400**)
Shape Test(2987, **400**)
```

The input shapes were each:

```
np.asarray(X_train).shape)
(11948, **200**)
(2987, **200**)
```

**Is this correct?** I expected the number of dimensions to be 200 again.

Answer (score 1):

This is correct. `PV-DM` and `PV-DBOW` are two different models, each producing different embeddings of dimension `dim`, where `dim=200` in your case. Hence, when concatenating the dimension should double.